# RViz crashes upon first /scan

Tags: lidar, rviz, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm having a serious problem getting RViz to operate on a FitPC2 (dreaded GMA500 embedded system) with a SICK TiM310 scanner.

The FitPC2 is currently running Ubuntu 12.04, ROS-Groovy and RViz 1.9.34 as our primary research platforms are designed around a PandaBoard, but this specific research problem requires some of the x86 packages that are not yet ARMHF compiled for Hydro. We will upgrade along that path at some point.

Currently I am able to run RViz fine, but as soon as the first /scan data is published by the SICK_TiM3xx package, RViz crashes with the following terminal information: http://pastebin.com/euHWXPBD

I have confirmed that the output of the LiDAR is correct by other means, but it would be extremely valuable to us to be able to visualise the scan data in real-time on the platform.

Any help that someone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/158561/rviz-crashes-upon-first-/scan/) by [anonymousSnowMan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3930/anonymoussnowman/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2014-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a bug in rviz 1.9.34 that causes crashes like this (see second post [on rviz ticket 736](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/736)). One option is to down- or upgrading your rviz version, another is using the hydro version installed from .debs.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-04-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0